# how to pass an string value in url in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=catId&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder"]];

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

i have this url i want that category-selected=350 should get value from Variable how to do this 
I am doing but not getting result if i give var name instead of 350.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.businessfactors.de/bfcms/images/stories/videos/%@.mp4",strtext]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSString [stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) to format the URL with the ivar:

```
NSString *catId = @"350";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=%@&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder", catId];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Comment: may i put all url in NSString

Comment: -[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9307c60
 this is giving exception when i am using this

Comment: If your parameter is an integer, you should be using the %d argument instead of %@. See [Apple's Format Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

for sending use stringByURLEncode, stringByURLDecode

```
 - (NSString *)stringByURLDecode {

        NSMutableString *tempStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self];
        [tempStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" " options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length])];

        return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }

    - (NSString *)stringByURLEncode {

        NSMutableString *tempStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self];
        [tempStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length])];


        return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempStr] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }
```